# Objects and transferring objects between methods

Tags: java, oop

I am learning Java pretty new and I am basically at the beginner level.
I am working on a small project totally meaningless but only for the purpose of learning OOP.

Here is the code I did below and my notes.

```
public void main() {
    Notebook noteBook = new Notebook();  //I add notebook just to track my notes on the subject
    Konto kontobank = kontoErsteller();
    // So here it worked but I did not understand how and why
    // It might be the scope problem here. I did not even understand why
    // Konto Kontobank = bankKonto1 worked? (bankKonto1 is the returned
    // value)
    int x = start(kontobank); //so that funtion returns something.
}

/*
 * Here I create default 2 kontos. So that I can transfer money in between. Also in real life
 * in a bank when we habve thebankcard that means we already have an account.
 * I return an integer value back to track if things went ok
 */
public Konto kontoErsteller() {
    int kontoErstellerReturn = 0;
    Konto bankKonto1 = new Konto();
    Konto bankKonto2 = new Konto();
    return bankKonto1;
}

/*
* I will start with entrance but I should return to the owner of 
* account1 so I should be manupulating bankKonto1
 */
public int start(Konto bankKonto) {
    Konto bankKonto1 = bankKonto;
    Entrance neuEnterance = new Entrance();

    //KontoMenu kontoMenu=new KontoMenu(bankKonto.getUniqID());
    String[] statuse = neuEnterance.start();
    //System.out.println(statuse);

    if (statuse[0] == "True") {
        System.out.println("Entered");
        //Konto bankKonto=new Konto();
        System.out.println("Hello " + bankKonto1.getKontoOwner());
        System.out.println("Your current status is " + bankKonto1.getInitialGeld() + " €");
        double newValue = menuItem(Double.parseDouble(bankKonto1.getInitialGeld()));
        bankKonto1.setNewAmount(newValue);
        System.out.println("Your new status is " + bankKonto1.getInitialGeld() + " €");

        //KontoMenu kontoMenu=new KontoMenu(bankKonto.getUniqID());
        //kontoMenu.menuItem(bankKonto.getUniqID());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So I actually did not wish to send Konto object I wanted to create them in kontoErsteller and then use them whenever I want with their names bankKonto1 and bankKonto2

```
Konto kontobank = kontoErsteller();
int x = start(kontobank);
```

So my question is 
So here it worked but I did not understand how and why. I did not even understand why `Konto kontobank = bankKonto1` worked?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly is your question. Which part of your code don't you understand? What exactly do you mean by "it works"?

Comment: In the method `kontoErsteller()` you return a `Konto`, but your comment says you "return an integer". What are you really trying to do? Perhaps you can try a simpler example first, where it is easier to explain what is unclear to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"So I actually did not wish to send Konto object I wanted to create them in kontoErsteller and then use them whenever I want with their names bankKonto1 and bankKonto2"

You don't want them to be local variables in the `kontoErsteller` method but instead class members. For this to makes sense you should probably have two classes, a `Konto` class and one class that handle `Konto` objects. So let's call this class KontoHandler

```
public class KontoHandler {
    Konto bankKonto1;
    Konto bankKonto2;

}
```

Then creating the objects can be done in the constructor of this class instead of `kontoErsteller`

```
 public class KontoHandler {
    Konto bankKonto1;
    Konto bankKonto2;

    public KontoHandler() {
         bankKonto1 = new Konto();
         bankKonto2 = new Konto();
    }
}
```

If you move the method `start` to this class you can access bankKonto1  and bankKonto2 from inside it without needing to send a konto as a parameter

```
public int start() {
    Entrance neuEnterance = new Entrance();
    ...
}
```

This is just an example but the main point is to differentiate between your data object, Konto, and the handling of that object

Comment: This answer helped me to understand and solve my problem. I was also trying to solve some funtions out of my object and moved them in (money transfer checks etc..). Over all it simplified my code.